# Github Project page not detecting CSS changes

Tags: html, css, github

I created a project page pulling from the gh-pages branch. However, it doesn't seem to detect the styles in the CSS sheet even though the repository is up to date. I want the map image to be center with margin-left and right auto. Does anyone know why this might be?

The project page is at https://nattyrye.github.io/ames/

My repository - https://github.com/nattyrye/ames/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Style.css">`

to

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

The file style.css has a lowercase 's'

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it is not detecting your relative links:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
```

Try changing them to

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "../Style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../normalize.css">
```

so github knows what files you're talking about.

Make sure you use case sensitive file names too!